# Flutter install problem on macos el capitan

Tags: flutter, dart

i am on macos el capitan and I tried to install flutter and I am getting this error.

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _getentropy
Referenced from: /Users/ozturkmedia/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _getentropy
Referenced from: /Users/ozturkmedia/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: any luck? I am facing the same issue